# R: printing closure function source code directly into file

Tags: r

I want to overwrite a function (let's say function `do_something(...)`) of an R package with my own version. Unfortunately the function is too long to copy & paste it directly after typing `do_something` into the console. Is there a way to print the source code directly into a file?

Comment: Try `cat(capture.output(print(do_something)),file="afile.R", sep="\n")`

Comment: You can also use `writeLines` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @nicola Do you want to add your solution to my answer, and turn it into a community wiki?

Comment: Why don't you simply take it from the package's source?

Comment: @Roland  I am not sure it is really simple, particularly for Windows users.

Comment: @Pascal It's only one weblink followed by unpacking away. What's not simple about that?

Comment: @Roland  It is a tar.gz. A lot of people will be discouraged. Or simply won't think it can be opened easily.

Comment: @nicola I really like your solution ... it works and is one line. Thanks a lot! Maybe you should post is as answer. I want to accept :-)

Comment: @Pascal Umm, if someone is discouraged by a tar.gz, maybe they should reconsider doing programming.

Comment: @Roland I like your suggestion, since it is a good practice to learn that source code is there and available and one should know how to get it. However, I also agree with Pascal in that writing a single `R` line is simpler.

Comment: @Pascal How to do to make a community wiki? I'd also gladly add the Roland approach, which is very "pedagogical".

Comment: @Nicola  I can edit my answer and turn it into community wiki. I think anybody can edit here to add other approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example with `cor.test` function:

```
zz <- file("cor.test.txt", open = "wt")
sink(zz)
dput(stats:::cor.test.default)
sink()
close(zz)
```

In the above approach, we made use of `sink`, which redirects the output you normally have on the console to the `cor.test.txt` file. With the last line (`sink()`) we get back to normal.

Another approach is to use `capture.output`: it gets the output shown in the console to a `character` vector, which you can write to a file through `cat`:

```
cat(capture.output(print(do_something)),file="afile.R", sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the package's CRAN page and download the tar.gz. You might need to install additional software on Windows for unpacking tar.gz files, but freeware is available for this. Unpack the file and look into the R directory inside the unpacked package source. The function's source code is in one of the files there (the file names usually are informative).

The advantage of this method is that you get the source code **including comments**, which the other proposed methods won't give you.

Many packages also have their source code on GitHub or other similar platforms, where it is even easier to get.

Comment: Good luck to Windows users.

Comment: This is inconvenient and did not answer my question.  I asked for printing directly into a file.

Comment: @Roland I am not worried about you. But a lot of Windows users are not familiar with tar.gz. They mainly know .zip. So, if they see a .tar.gz, do you think they will even try to open it? (a previous Windows user).

Comment: @corinna You are free to do that. I'll leave this answer for others, because source code with comments is better than uncommented code.